# unable to dd, smartmon, fdisk or anything on a working external Western Digital Hard Drive

Tags: linux, partition, dd, gdisk

I bought a WD HD on Amazon used because I wanted one that was exactly like another that I hosed.

I can't do anything with the HD.

The drive is definitely /dev/sdb, but it also mounts /dev/sr0

```
~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   900M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 343.1G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 314.4G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0  19.5G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda7   8:7    0   350M  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0    20G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1    30M  0 rom
```

### fdisk

Trying to use fdisk on either device (partition?) gives me the same error

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

### dd

Even `dd` won't write zeros to the devices

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=1 of=/dev/sdb
dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.0011181 s, 0.0 kB/s

$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=1 of=/dev/sr0
dd: failed to open '/dev/sr0': Read-only file system
```

### wipefs and cfdisk

I tried using wipefs and cfdisk, without any success:

```
$ sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
$ sudo cfdisk /dev/sr0 
cfdisk: cannot open /dev/sr0: Read-only file system
$ sudo wipefs /dev/sr0 
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x0                  mac   [partition table]

0x8001               udf   [filesystem]
                     LABEL: WD Unlocker
                     UUID:  50EB4C87

$ sudo wipefs -a /dev/sr0 
wipefs: error: /dev/sr0: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
$ sudo wipefs -a /dev/sr0 
wipefs: error: /dev/sr0: probing initialization failed: Device or resource busy
$ sudo wipefs --all -f /dev/sr0 
wipefs: error: /dev/sr0: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
```

### gdisk

I tried using gdisk, which I think says that the disk is working, with the v command.

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.


Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 732558325 free sectors (2.7 TiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 732558325 (2.7 TiB) in size.

Command (? for help): d
No partitions

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): Y

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdb.
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
The operation has completed successfully.
```

I rebooted and nothing was different, so I tried gdisk on the other device.

```
$ sudo gdisk /dev/sr0 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

NOTE: Write test failed with error number 30. It will be impossible to save
changes to this disk's partition table!

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: present
  GPT: not present


*******************************************************************
This disk appears to contain an Apple-format (APM) partition table!
It will be destroyed if you continue!
*******************************************************************

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): Y

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): U
Your option? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sr0.
Unable to open device '/dev/sr0' for writing! Errno is 30! Aborting write!

Command (? for help): v

No problems found. 15341 free sectors (30.0 MiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 15341 (30.0 MiB) in size.
```

### Long shot password reset attempt with WD-Decrypte

I also tried using what I thought would let me reset the password, if there there is one.
https://github.com/SofianeHamlaoui/WD-Decrypte

I didn't clone the repo, I just copied the python script and ran the following:

```
$ vi cookpw.py ## copy paste from the github repo
$ chmod u+x cookpw.py 
$ ./cookpw.py passwd >password.bin 
$ sg_raw -s 40 -i password.bin /dev/sdb c1 e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00
/dev/sdb: Permission denied
$ sudo sg_raw -s 40 -i password.bin /dev/sdb c1 e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00
SCSI Status: Check Condition 

Sense Information:
 Fixed format, current;  Sense key: Illegal Request
 Additional sense: Authentication failed

$ stat password.bin 
  File: 'password.bin'
  Size: 40          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 15205314    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/    xxxx)   Gid: ( 1002/    gene)
Access: 2020-08-14 01:03:29.395345709 -0500
Modify: 2020-08-14 01:02:38.939618244 -0500
Change: 2020-08-14 01:02:38.939618244 -0500
 Birth: -
$ sudo sg_raw -s 40 -i password.bin /dev/sdb c1 e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00
SCSI Status: Check Condition 

Sense Information:
 Fixed format, current;  Sense key: Not Ready
 Additional sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready

$ sudo sg_raw -s 40 -i password.bin /dev/sdb c1 e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00
SCSI Status: Check Condition 

Sense Information:
 Fixed format, current;  Sense key: Illegal Request
 Additional sense: Authentication failed
```

### Hard drive model

This is the hard drive I ordered:

WD My Book 3TB External Hard Drive Storage USB 3.0 File Backup and Storage

Model Number: WDBACW0030HBK-NESN

### File structure and GUI disk management tools in Windows and Linux

When I load it in disk managers (Windows or Ubuntu), everything useful is grayed out. I can't check the smart status, format, there is no drive letter.

The drive does appear in the Linux file browser, and I can see some default files, and copy them out.

```
$ tree /media/gene/WD\ Unlocker/
/media/gene/WD Unlocker/
├── autorun.inf
├── Extras
│   └── VCDVersion.xml
├── Unlock.exe
├── WD Quick Formatter.exe
└── WD SmartWare
    ├── Locale
    │   ├── cs_CZ.lproj
    │   │   ├── CSS
    │   │   │   └── WDSmartWareHelp.css
    │   │   ├── EULA.html
    │   │   ├── EX_UNLK0.html
    │   │   ├── EX_UNLK1B.html
    │   │   ├── EX_UNLK1.html
    │   │   ├── EX_UNLK3.html
    │   │   ├── localizable.strings
    │   │   ├── UNLK2.html
    │   │   └── VCDF.html
    │   ├── de_DE.lproj

... (lots of languages)...

    │   │   └── VCDF.html
    │   └── zh_TW.lproj
    │       ├── CSS
    │       │   └── WDSmartWareHelp.css
    │       ├── EULA.html
    │       ├── EX_UNLK0.html
    │       ├── EX_UNLK1B.html
    │       ├── EX_UNLK1.html
    │       ├── EX_UNLK3.html
    │       ├── localizable.strings
    │       ├── UNLK2.html
    │       └── VCDF.html
    └── SmartWare_CD.ico
```

### Conclusion

I thought this would be pretty easy to format, but I'm at my wit's end. Any ideas?

## EDIT Aug 14, 2020:

I added some headers and punctuation to make the question easier to navigate and am adding the following documentation:

### DMSG OUTPUT

**EDIT: UNFILTERED DMSG BELOW**

When I checked dmsg last night I thought that the "callbacks suppressed" numbers were higher; in the 50's. I have no idea what anything in dmsg means, but the callback part looked strange so I googled it (and still have no idea what it means).

```
$ dmesg  | grep -i scsi
[    0.304565] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    1.212532] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    1.414640] scsi host0: ahci
[    1.414791] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.414941] scsi host2: ahci
[    1.415069] scsi host3: ahci
[    1.764038] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 2J   PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.764616] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.877339] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  133.590618] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  134.589496] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1170     1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  134.590008] scsi 4:0:0:1: CD-ROM            WD       Virtual CD 1170  1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  134.591206] scsi 4:0:0:2: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  134.592861] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  134.594305] sr 4:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 51x/51x caddy
[  134.594664] sr 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  134.594971] sr 4:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  134.595493] scsi 4:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[  141.554025] scsi 4:0:0:2: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[  141.554033] scsi 4:0:0:2: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[  141.554038] scsi 4:0:0:2: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[  143.664433] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  232.696987] scsi_io_completion: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  347.602357] scsi_io_completion: 8 callbacks suppressed
[  363.163922] scsi_io_completion: 7 callbacks suppressed
[  668.971338] scsi_io_completion: 8 callbacks suppressed
```

### SMART monitoring

Using smartctl on /dev/sdb doesn't work, I needed to add the -d option.

However, this was interesting:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a -T verypermissive /dev/sdb 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-184-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sdb: Unknown USB bridge [0x1058:0x1170 (0x1042)]
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

I feel like I've seen this USB bridge error before, but I did switch cables in case it was a physical cable issue (it wasn't).

After some research I added the -d scsi option and I get this:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a -d scsi -T verypermissive /dev/sdb 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-184-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               WD
Product:              My Book 1170
Revision:             1042
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        3,000,558,944,256 bytes [3.00 TB]
Logical block size:   4096 bytes
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Serial number:        WCC1T0867040
Device type:          disk
Local Time is:        Fri Aug 14 09:19:09 2020 CDT
device Test Unit Ready  [unknown error (unexpected sense key)]
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===

Error Counter logging not supported

No self-tests have been logged
```

The smartctl command on /dev/sr0 doesn't need the scsi specification, who knows why?

```
$ sudo smartctl -a -T verypermissive /dev/sr0 
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-184-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               WD
Product:              Virtual CD 1170
Revision:             1042
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        31,457,280 bytes [31.4 MB]
Logical block size:   2048 bytes
Serial number:        WCC1T0867040
Device type:          CD/DVD
Local Time is:        Fri Aug 14 09:19:36 2020 CDT
SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===

Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

I think these results say that the disk is present, but there is no logging? Do I need to turn on smartctl?

I noticed this in the documentation:

```
       smartctl --smart=on --offlineauto=on --saveauto=on /dev/sda
       Enable  SMART  on  drive  /dev/sda, enable automatic offline testing every four hours, and enable autosaving of SMART Attributes.  This is a good start-up line for your system´s init files.  You can
       issue this command on a running system.
```

### READ ONLY - hdparm and physical drive

I neglected to mention that one of the first things I did was issue these commands:

```
$ sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb 

/dev/sdb:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
$ sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sr0 

/dev/sr0:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

This did nothing to resolve the read only status.

Also, there is no lock switch anywhere on the hard drive, and I've pressed the power button several times over the past couple of weeks since getting the drive.

## Edit Aug 14, 2020 (2)

After reattaching the hard drive these are my messages:

```
[29847.050551] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[29851.566835] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[29851.583422] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1170
[29851.583426] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[29851.583430] usb 2-2: Product: My Book 1170
[29851.583433] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[29851.583435] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 574343315430383637303430
[29851.584159] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[29851.584269] scsi host5: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[29852.583294] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1170     1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29852.583557] scsi 5:0:0:1: CD-ROM            WD       Virtual CD 1170  1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29852.584436] scsi 5:0:0:2: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1042 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[29852.586165] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[29852.587224] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[29852.587638] sr 5:0:0:1: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 51x/51x caddy
[29852.589827] sr 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[29852.590297] sr 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[29852.592576] ses 5:0:0:2: Attached Enclosure device
[29852.592932] ses 5:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[29852.593612] ses 5:0:0:2: Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 0
[29852.593627] ses 5:0:0:2: Failed to get diagnostic page 0xffffffea
[29852.593638] ses 5:0:0:2: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[29853.590968] ..not responding...
[29861.407668] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 732558336 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[29861.429631] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[29861.429639] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
[29861.447321] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[29861.447326] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[29861.507569] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[29861.507576] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.507581] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.596816] scsi_io_completion: 7 callbacks suppressed
[29861.596824] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.596828] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.596833] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.596837] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.596840] blk_update_request: 7 callbacks suppressed
[29861.596842] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.596845] buffer_io_error: 4 callbacks suppressed
[29861.596848] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.618633] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.618639] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.618644] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.618648] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.618651] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.618654] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.632833] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.632839] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.632844] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.632848] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.632851] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.632854] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.632872] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[29861.651594] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.651599] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.651604] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.651608] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.651610] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.651613] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.673907] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.673914] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.673919] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.673924] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.673927] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.673931] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.695989] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.695995] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.696000] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.696004] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.696007] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.696010] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.715645] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.715653] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.715658] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.715662] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.715665] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.715668] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.715697] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[29861.735908] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.735914] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.735919] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.735923] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.735926] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.735929] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.736644] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.736649] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.736653] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.736657] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 01 00
[29861.736660] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 24
[29861.736662] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[29861.737092] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[29861.737096] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.737100] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.737104] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[29861.737107] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[29861.737109] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[29861.737478]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[29861.738776] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[29861.738787] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[29861.738793] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[29861.739986] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

I'm not sure what these mean, but I see a lot error messages and something indicating that I'm unauthorized.

## Conclusion Edit: Aug 14, 2020

After taking some advice below (@paul-pedant) I'm taking the very unsatisfying route of reformatting using WD's proprietary software. It's unbelievable that none of these low level utilities could simply format the drive.

[image]

Comment: check `dmesg` for errors related to that disk, sounds like the disk is broken.

Comment: do a S.M.A.R.T. analysis i bet the drive is end-of-life and therefore read-only (that is the last state before complete failure)

Comment: I've added some dmesg and S.M.A.R.T. analysis. I always check `dmesg`, but it's about as useful to me as looking at a binary in a text editor. I have no idea what most of these things mean.

Comment: @eblock if you wouldn't mind looking at the last addition, do you know what this means? Is it a physical failure or a permission issue?

Comment: In my mind I'm saying "COMPUTER, I SAID *SUDO*!", I can't understand how it's saying that something's read only / I'm unauthorized / etc. Make the sandwich already.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is write-protected as external HDDs commonly has this feature, 'SR0' is probably OEM partition with software of this hdd.
I would suggest to download/install WDs proprietary software on windows machine and see if it can provide you with anything useful.
If I get it right, it is used drive, so previous owner could have locked drive or similar.

Comment: There are many Google hits for WD Unlocker. There is also Community.WD.com. Most people want to recover their own data, but it looks like a complete wipe is an easier option. The .html files that you can read from sr0 may be informative too.

Comment: Yes, I found those and was already on the path for doing a complete wipe, but nothing seems to wipe it.  I'm ready to buy a strong magnet. And I did contact the seller to ask if there was a password.

Comment: It seems that I would need the password to unlock it, so I don't see why I can't use dd to erase it.

Comment: The files in sr0 were not helpful, but you're right that I need the WD proprietary software. After downloading WD Drive Utilities from https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx and entering 5 bad passwords it let me wipe it.

Answer (score 1):

To all intents and purposes this is a dead disk. The original owner has locked it in some way and so it's no longer a working or useful device.

Recommendation? Don't waste any more time on it but instead return it to the sender and claim your payment back.

Comment: I was about to do so, but it appears that the proprietary software will remove the lock.

Comment: Good luck with that. IMO it should never have been resold on like that in the first place.

Comment: Normally, I would never buy a used hard drive (esp not SSD). In this case I wanted an exact replica of another drive I damaged 4 years ago, and would like to copy with dd and and hopefully recover. It only has to work for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: Write test failed with error number 30

makes Devourer's answer highly probable.
as errno 30 = Read-Only filesystem.

---

But that might not be enough depending on your kernel / fdisk version ?

Your HD appears to be a 4K logical / 4K physical sector size.

Rather old linux & fdisk (*) did not support 4K logical disks.

=> Under such systems, You must get ? activate ? some firmware to have this device expose these 4K sectors as 8 contiguous 512B logical sectors.

---

(*) Cannot precisely tell but at least Read-hat / CentOS 5, fdisk- 2.17 did not.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS. I do run apt updates frequently, but are you saying that my OS is too old?